# What is possible is also feasible?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, synonyms

I know how to use *possible* but I am doubtful how to use *feasible* in a sentence.

> It is not possible to speak like a native speaker.

I have referred to Longman’s Active Study Dictionary and The Word Master but they did not show any examples to make the distinction clear.

They treated both  **possible** and
 **feasible** almost similarly.

I here with attach a link which can not clarify  my question.

https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/

My question is:

what is possible is also feasible?

Comment: I'd like to see a Long Man's dictionary.

Comment: Long Man's is not the same as Longman's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two words are very similar in meaning and often interchangeable (synonyms).

The Cambridge Dictionary defines feasible as
[possible to do and likely to be successful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feasible)

And possible as
[able to be done or achieved, or able to exist](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possible)

As you can see, almost the same. However "possible" has a broader usage. There are many instances where you couldn't substitute "feasible". For example

> It is **possible** there will be rain.

"feasible" doesn't work in idiomatic English in this case.

"Feasible" is mostly associated with some sort of action. Feasible to go, feasible to make and so on and there is a expectation of success.

"Possible" can be substituted in these phrases but success is not necessarily expected and it has a broader application to other things such as events (example above) and existence where "feasible" doesn't work.

> It is **possible** there is water in that jug.

Comment: When you say *"possible" has a broader usage,* I'm assuming you really mean ***is more common***. But *semantically*, I think ***feasible*** can sometimes have a "broader reach" than ***possible***, in that sometimes ***feasible = capable of being imagined***, a category which I would say includes ***possible = capable of being instantiated*** as a subset. Strangely though, I find written instances of ***possible but not feasible*** massively outnumber ***feasible but not possible*** in Google Books, so maybe I'm just on the wrong track there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe. I have in my mind a [venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) where "feasible" is almost entirely inside "possible". But then again  I too could be wrong.

Comment: Well, I guess etymologically the boot is on your foot, since *feasible* stems from "to make" (something real, to "reify"). But it still seems to me *technically **feasible but** in practice **not possible*** sounds a lot more natural than *technically **possible but** in practice **not feasible***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is turning into a discussion, frowned upon in comments, but I agree that "_technically **feasible but** in practice **not possible**_" is more natural. Actually I think we are in agreement, just looking at it from slightly different angles. I don't know the etymology, but Latin fecit - to make - seems highly plausible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers By my first comment I meant that **nearly** everywhere you see "feasible" you can substitute "possible" and get virtually the same meaning, but the reverse isn't true IMHO. The one exception that springs to mind is "feasibility study" where you never hear "possibility study". Maybe it's more what I'm are used to hearing in idiomatic BrE rather than anything else.

Comment: I agree "feasibility study" is an odd one in this area. For a similar usage restriction going the other way, I note that we can say *This plan is just one possibility*, but we can't say *This plan is just one feasibility*.

Answer (score 0):

"Possible" implies possible to do and possible to happen.
"Feasible" just implies possible to do.

If we can make it happen, then it is feasible or possible
If the chance is involved, then it is possible, but not feasible.